# Replacement for commit_on_success

Tags: python, database, django, atomic

I am porting an application from django 1.4.5 to django 1.6.1. I found that `commit_on_success` has been deprecated. Moreover I found specific incompatibilities when calling `get_or_create` from inside `commit_on_success`.

`atomic` is often mentioned as drop-in replacement for `commit_on_success`, but using `atomic` alone does not always guaranteed durability, and there appear to be no official solution to that problem.

I have tried writing a replacement for `commit_on_success` by building on top of `atomic` and adding back in the durability guarantee. Does this code look like it solves the problem? Are there cases, where this code would fail to provide atomicity and durability?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try: from django.db.transaction import (Atomic, TransactionManagementError,
                                        get_connection)
except ImportError: from django.db.transaction import commit_on_success
else:
    class DurableAtomic(Atomic):
        def __enter__(self):
            if get_connection(self.using).in_atomic_block:
                raise TransactionManagementError(
                    "Cannot use DurableAtomic inside Atomic")
            super(DurableAtomic, self).__enter__()
    def commit_on_success(using=None):
        if callable(using):
            return DurableAtomic(None, False)(using)
        return DurableAtomic(using, False)
```

As suggested by [Quentin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11227/quentin-pradet) I have written unit tests for the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.transaction import atomic, TransactionManagementError
from core.commit_on_success import commit_on_success
from django.test import TransactionTestCase

def update_user(username):
    User.objects.filter(username=username) \
                .update(email=username + '@example.org')

def is_updated(username):
    return '.org' in User.objects.get(username=username).email

class TestException(Exception):
    pass

class TestValidation(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user('a', 'a@example.com', 'aaa')
        User.objects.create_user('b', 'b@example.com', 'bbb')
        User.objects.create_user('c', 'c@example.com', 'ccc')

    # First test nesting of @atomic and @commit_on_success
    # There are four combinations, but nesting atomic inside atomic is
    # outside of scope for this test case.

    # atomic inside commit_on_success is appropriate usage and must work.

    def test_atomic_in_commit_on_success(self):
        @atomic
        def inner():
            update_user('b')

        @commit_on_success
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            inner()
            update_user('c')

        outer()

        self.assertTrue(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('c'))

    # commit_on_success inside atomic is inappropriate and must raise an
    # exception. Test catching the exception inside as well as outside the
    # outermost block.

    def test_commit_on_success_in_atomic(self):
        @commit_on_success
        def inner():
            update_user('b')

        @atomic
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            inner()
            update_user('c')

        self.assertRaises(TransactionManagementError, outer)

        self.assertFalse(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('c'))

    def test_commit_on_success_in_atomic_handled(self):
        @commit_on_success
        def inner():
            update_user('b')

        @atomic
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            self.assertRaises(TransactionManagementError, inner)
            update_user('c')

        outer()

        self.assertTrue(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('c'))

    # commit_on_success inside commit_on_success is inappropriate and must
    # raise an exception. Test catching the exception inside as well as
    # outside the outermost block.

    def test_commit_on_success_in_commit_on_success(self):
        @commit_on_success
        def inner():
            update_user('b')

        @commit_on_success
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            inner()
            update_user('c')

        self.assertRaises(TransactionManagementError, outer)

        self.assertFalse(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('c'))

    def test_commit_on_success_in_commit_on_success_handled(self):
        @commit_on_success
        def inner():
            update_user('b')

        @commit_on_success
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            self.assertRaises(TransactionManagementError, inner)
            update_user('c')

        outer()

        self.assertTrue(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('c'))

    # Next test the appropriate nesting with an exception raised at
    # interesting points during execution.

    def test_exception_in_inner(self):
        @atomic
        def inner():
            update_user('b')
            raise TestException

        @commit_on_success
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            inner()
            update_user('c')

        self.assertRaises(TestException, outer)

        self.assertFalse(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('c'))

    def test_exception_in_inner_handled(self):
        @atomic
        def inner():
            update_user('b')
            raise TestException

        @commit_on_success
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            self.assertRaises(TestException, inner)
            update_user('c')

        outer()

        self.assertTrue(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('c'))

    def test_exception_in_outer(self):
        @atomic
        def inner():
            update_user('b')

        @commit_on_success
        def outer():
            update_user('a')
            inner()
            update_user('c')
            # Raising an exception at this exact point of execution means it
            # will be impossible to simultaneously provide durability for the
            # inner block and atomicity for the outer block.
            # Had the innermost block asked for durability, we would have
            # raised TransactionManagementError before reaching this point.
            raise TestException

        self.assertRaises(TestException, outer)

        # Innermost block didn't ask for durability, and it didn't get it.
        # Atomicity for the outer block is preserved, in this particular case
        # by rolling back the transaction due to the exception.
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertFalse(is_updated('c'))

    # Finally test using as context handler rather than decorator

    def test_as_context(self):
        with commit_on_success():
            update_user('a')
            with atomic():
                update_user('b')
            update_user('c')

        self.assertTrue(is_updated('a'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('b'))
        self.assertTrue(is_updated('c'))
```

Comment: Thank your for the tests! Can you license your code to something else than the default cc by-sa 3.0?

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, this clever code solves your problem : you won't be able to nest `commit_on_success` or `atomic` under `commit_on_success`. You already know the caveats, but I'll repeat them anyway:

   - If you do nest a block under a `commit_on_success`, your code will consistently fail: easy to fix *as long as* this code path is executed in your tests.
   - It's always possible to commit manually using `connection.commit()`, maybe you're using a library that does weird things, say by having its own transaction manager.
   - It's easy to maliciously change DurableAtomic.
2. Please, please write tests for this, to see that you *do* get the correct behaviour with and without nesting, with and without exceptions.
3. Nested `atomic` blocks map conceptually well with one big transaction for the outer block and savepoints for the nested blocks. I agree with Kevin Christopher Henry in your [SO answer about `commit_on_success` going away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24108491/): your concept of "durability without atomicity" doesn't make much sense, I would prefer to rewrite the code if possible to avoid relying on the dubious behavior of `commit_on_success`.
4. I've indented your try/except to be PEP8-compliant:

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   try:
       from django.db.transaction import (Atomic, TransactionManagementError,
                                          get_connection)
   except ImportError:
       from django.db.transaction import commit_on_success
   else:
       class DurableAtomic(Atomic):
           def __enter__(self):
               if get_connection(self.using).in_atomic_block:
                   raise TransactionManagementError(
                       "Cannot use DurableAtomic inside Atomic")
               super(DurableAtomic, self).__enter__()

       def commit_on_success(using=None):
           if callable(using):
               return DurableAtomic(None, False)(using)
           return DurableAtomic(using, False)
   ```

Comment: You are right, I should definitely write more unit tests for this. Would it be a good idea to amend my question with unit tests?

Comment: I'm not sure what the policy is about changing questions, but yeah, go for it! Having a small Django app on git or similar could make things easier to test too. But yeah, I'd like to see the tests.

Comment: I don't get your third point. Conceptually durability and atomicity can be completely separated. There may not be a use case for durability without atomicity, but the concept could be implemented regardless. However there are very clear use cases for atomicity both with and without the durability guarantee. And I decided only to implement the combination of the two (because that was easier and covered my needs). Nesting of `commit_on_success` was never a good idea, and my replacement does not even try to support that.

Comment: You're saying that `BEGIN TRANSACTION; UPDATE1; SAVEPOINT S; UPDATE2; ROLLBACK to S; COMMIT;` breaks durability because you lost `UPDATE2`, I'm saying "You asked for it". Nothing else to add. :)

Comment: The innermost code using `atomic` did not perform a `ROLLBACK`, neither did it ask for one. It would in fact trigger the creation of a savepoint, but rather than rolling back to that savepoint, it would trigger a `savepoint_commit`. Some other code then later caused a rollback or an abort of the entire transaction. The author of that code wasn't asking for it. He wasn't asking to have his code executed in a context where `atomic` provide no durability guarantees.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, it's the other way around. But AFAIK the general issue stays the same. We'll have to agree to disagree!