# Transaction.atomic with continuations

Tags: python, database, django, atomic

I have a view that looks like this:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def view(request):
    do_stuff(...)  
    if condition(...):
        result = do_other_stuff(...)
        transaction.commit()
        send_email(result)
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

Assume everything with (...) can touch the database.

There are currently two main cases:

1. condition is true, `do_stuff()` and `do_other_stuff()` are done in transaction 1, the transaction is saved, then the e-mail is sent and `HttpResponse` is done in transaction 2
2. condition is false, everything happens in transaction 2

I want to rewrite this with `transaction.atomic`. The important requirement is: the e-mail should only be sent if `do_other_stuff()` really gets saved.

Obviously I can't use `@atomic` around the whole view, because I wouldn't be able to commit, so my first shot looks something like:

```
def view(request):
    should_send_email = False
    with transaction.atomic:
        do_stuff(...)
        if condition(...):
            result = do_other_stuff(...)
            should_send_email = True
        response = HttpResponse(...)
    if should_send_email:
        should_send_email(result)
    return response
```

It's kind of acceptable, but it clobbers the control flow. How to rewrite it better?

I was thinking about something like:

```
def view(request):
    with AtomicWithContinuation as a:  # new context manager
        do_stuff(...)
        if condition(...):
            result = do_other_stuff(...)
            a.after_commit(lambda: send_email(result))
        return HttpResponse(...)
```

which looks easier on the eyes, so I've rolled up a context manager like:

```
class AtomicWithContinuation(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.atomic = transaction.atomic(*args, **kwargs)
        self._after_commit = []
        self._after_rollback = []

    def after_commit(self, cb):
        self._after_commit.append(cb)

    def after_rollback(self, cb):
        self._after_rollback.append(cb)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.atomic.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        try:
            self.atomic.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        except Exception:
            # atomic.__exit__ itself threw an exception
            # - assume a rollback has been done
            for cb in self._after_rollback:
                cb()
            raise
        if exc_val is not None:
            # Wrapped block raised an exception,
            # so atomic had to do a rollback
            for cb in self._after_rollback:
                cb()
        else:
            for cb in self._after_commit:
                cb()
```

Does this implementation make sense? Is this a good approach to take? Also, can I trust my assumptions in `__exit__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there's anything wrong with the `should_send_email` version of the code. But I can see that in more complex cases there would be a readability benefit in keeping the after-commit logic next to the condition.
2. There's no documentation. How do I use the `AtomicWithContinuation` class? What methods does it have? What guarantees does it provide about which callbacks will be called, when, and in what order?
3. The name could be improved: [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) are not the same as [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).
4. It would make sense for the `after_commit` and `after_rollback` methods to take `*args` and `**kwargs` to be passed to the callback:

   ```
   def after_commit(self, cb, *args, **kwargs):
       """Call cb, passing *args and **kwargs, when this transction commits."""
       self._after_commit.append((cb, args, kwargs))
   ```

   That would allow you to omit the `lambda`:

   ```
   a.after_commit(send_email, result)
   ```
5. There's repeated code for calling all the callbacks in a list. This could be made into a function:

   ```
   def run_callbacks(callbacks):
       """Run the callbacks in the iterable."""
       for cb, args, kwargs in callbacks:
           cb(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
6. You ask, "can I trust my assumptions in `__exit__`?" Well, there seem to be three assumptions:

   1. If `atomic.__exit__` is called with `exc_val=None`, it commits the transaction.
   2. If `atomic.__exit__` is called with any other value of `exc_val`, it rolls back the transaction.
   3. If `atomic.__exit__` raises an exception, then the transaction was rolled back.

   Assumptions 1 and 2 are guaranteed by the [docstring for the `Atomic` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/transaction.py#L110), which says:

   > `__exit__` commits the transaction or releases the savepoint on normal exit, and rolls back the transaction or to the savepoint on exceptions.

   It would be worth adding a comment to your `__exit__` method quoting or linking to this guarantee.

   Assumption 3 is not guaranteed anywhere I can find, and a look at the source for the [`Atomic.__exit__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/transaction.py#L196) method shows that it *tries* to roll back the transaction, but this might fail, possibly ending up with the connection being closed, or the `needs_rollback` flag being set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough review! I think my main problem with the `should_send_email` version was that I couldn't use early returns there. About the assumptions- looks like `after_rollback` is not something I can guarantee in general (since the rollback can fail), so perhaps I should rename it. Also in order to guarantee `after_commit`, I should verify if the atomic block is the outermost block, so that it really commits rather than just makes a savepoint (see [Replacement for commit_on_success](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/53751/replacement-for-commit-on-success)).